# Check when page scroll reach multiple different divs, animate counter from 0 to text element

Tags: jquery, math, svg, scroll, svg-animate

I need to check when page scroll reach specifics different divs, and then start animate the svg pie-chart and the progressive percentage number.

I take the percentage value from the text insert in each H3 of the container elements, then I create the content elements and I use this variable for setting the "to" attribute of svg animate tag and the span text for the counter.

On scroll page I call the "go" function for start the svg animation and then I start the counter animation.

Page test [here](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test/pie-chart-animation-test.html)

I have two problems:

1-All animations starts simultaneously when reached the first div container, I want that every single animation start when page scroll reach the respective containers;

2-Even if the progressive number animation start from 0 before the animation start it's showing the final value.
Can someone help me?

```
//// JQUERY
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".phps_contenuti_pagina").each(function () {
        hit_elem =  $(this);
        //var for getting the percentage number from h3
        number_perc = $(this).children("h3").text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
        //I create the html element with span and svg tags and I use the var above for settin the span text and the "to" animate attr
        $(this).append('<div><span class="count">'+number_perc+'%</span><svg  width="300" height="300"viewbox="0 0 400 400"><defs><clipPath id="counter-clippath"><rect x="50" y="0" width="320" height="72" /></clipPath></defs><circle fill="#ccc" cx="200" cy="200" r="200" /><circle cx="200" cy="200" r="160" transform="rotate(-90, 200, 200)" stroke-dasharray="0, 1000" stroke="#7cb342" stroke-width="80" data-fallback="edge"><animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" to="'+number_perc+'0,1000" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" /></circle><circle cx="200" cy="200" r="160" fill="#fff" /></svg></div></div>')
    });
});     

//function to start the svg animation
function go () {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("animate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].beginElement();
  }
}

//I call the above funtcion when page scroll reach container elements and then i start the counter animation
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var hT = hit_elem.offset().top,
        hH = hit_elem.outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        //call go function
        go();

        //I switch off the scroll function to prevent the animation from continue running
        $(window).off('scroll');

        //counter animation
        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 900,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```
/* CSS */
body{margin-top:50vh;margin-bottom:200vh;}
.phps_contenuti_pagina{display:inline-block;width:100%;}
.phps_contenuti_pagina > div{ float:left;position:relative;}
span.count{width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:100px;left:50px;font-size:100px;text-align:center;}
```

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="phps_contenuti_pagina">
  <h3>Lorem 40%</h3>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<div class="phps_contenuti_pagina">
  <h3>Ipsum 20%</h3>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

I've tried to set progressive id numbers for each container and use  them when I set the container .offset().top and .outerHeight() vars ,but it doesn't work.

I've tried to set the percentage value to 0 and then recall the 'number_perc' var before the counter function but it give me only the percentage number of the last div container

Comment: In your scroll event handler, you'll need to loop through each of your divs and check whether they are visible.  Then start that particular animation only.  At the moment `hit_elem` is being set once at the start, and your `go()` function is starting all of them.  You need to do a bit of code rearranging. You are most of the way there already. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much [Paul Le Beau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) after some tests I did it!

So I have removed the **"hit_elem" var** and I have setted an ".inactive" class to all div elements.

In the scroll event handler I have setted an each function for ".inactive" divs, inside it I have created the **".offset.top, outerHeight, window.height and window.scroll" variables** for check when the page_scroll reach this element, then for each element I remove "inactive" and add "active" class.

In this way I can call the **"go" function** only for the **.active animate elements** and make the counter only for the **.active.count span.**

```js
//// JQUERY
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".phps_contenuti_pagina").each(function() {
    //var for getting the percentage number from h3
    number_perc = $(this).children("h3").text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    //I create the html element with span and svg tags and I use the var above for settin the span text and the "to" animate attr
    $(this).append('<div><span class="count">' + number_perc + '%</span><svg  width="300" height="300"viewbox="0 0 400 400"><defs><clipPath id="counter-clippath"><rect x="50" y="0" width="320" height="72" /></clipPath></defs><circle fill="#ccc" cx="200" cy="200" r="200" /><circle cx="200" cy="200" r="160" transform="rotate(-90, 200, 200)" stroke-dasharray="0, 1000" stroke="#7cb342" stroke-width="80" data-fallback="edge"><animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="1s" to="' + number_perc + '0,1000" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" /></circle><circle cx="200" cy="200" r="160" fill="#fff" /></svg></div></div>')
  });
  //set inactive class to every phps_contenuti_pagina 
  $(".phps_contenuti_pagina").addClass("inactive");
});

//function to start the svg animation
function go() {
  var elements = $(".active animate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].beginElement();
  }
}

//Scroll function for start animations when each element is reached
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $(".inactive").each(function() {
    hT = $(this).offset().top,
      hH = $(this).outerHeight(),
      wH = $(window).height(),
      wS = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
      $(this).removeClass("inactive");
      //prevent any active class setted before by remove it on every phps_contenuti_pagina div
      $(".phps_contenuti_pagina").removeClass("active");
      //set the active class only for this phps_contenuti_pagina
      $(this).addClass("active");

      //call go function
      go();

      //counter animation only for active phps_contenuti_pagina span
      $(".active .count").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
          duration: 900,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + "%");
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 200vh;
}

.phps_contenuti_pagina {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.phps_contenuti_pagina>div {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

span.count {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phps_contenuti_pagina">
  <h3>Lorem 40%</h3>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<div class="phps_contenuti_pagina">
  <h3>Ipsum 20%</h3>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

It's that good? I'm not a good programmer can you give me some suggestions for make this code better?

Now still remain the problem number two, I need that the counter number show first zero, now it's showing the final value.
I've tried to set the value to zero inside the html built with the append method and then try to get the variable **"number_perc"** out from the each function but I know that I can't do that because of the scope.

I keep study on it maybe I can solve it by my self, but any suggestions can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this would be to use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Using this approach is more performant than listening to scroll events. What IO does is: It looks at an element and triggers a function when the observered element is in the viewport (based on your provided settings) or leaving the viewport.

First, you must define the options for your IO and initialize it:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '5px 10px', // works just like margin on element
  threshold: 0.9 // when ~90% of element is visible, trigger IO
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options); // trigger callback function when provided options match for an element
```

Then you have to define which elements to watch:

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.inactive'); // you want to watch multiple elements with inactive class
targets.forEach(target => { // loop through your elements
  observer.observe(target); // observe them
});

// the callback we setup for the observer will be executed now for the first time
// it waits until we assign a target to our observer (even if the target is currently not visible)
```

Last step is to define what should happen once an observed element reaches the viewport:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect...
    // Your .inactive element is in viewport.
  });
};
```

You can also [unobserve an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) when you only need to trigger this once.

A [polyfill from w3c exists](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support browsers who don't support IO (IE11).